# Email Address Validation. Is this Valid?

Tags: asp.net, regex, email, email-validation

I am using the asp.net validation control to validate email addresses. There was an issue with an email address because it has the following characters. "-." For example the email address w.-a.wsdf.com will not validate due to the ".-" in it. I was looking around for email standards that forbid this but could not find any. Should I change the asp.net regex to a custom one to allow this or is this not a valid email address?

The regex i am using now is : `\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*`

Comment: Just curious if you did not test it?

Comment: See also this question (from the "Related" section): http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/121309

Answer (score 0):

You'll get loads of answers for this. This one has always served me well:

```
/\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
```

Originally found it in Michael Hartl's Rails book

Comment: Doesn't support quoted strings, as in "the quick brown fox"@example.com - See http://cobisi.com/email-validation/.net-component/features/syntax-validation#quoted-strings

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]$
```

Comment: Please add a description of what the expression does, and reference its source (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are great but, as my comments showed in other answers, validating email addresses with them is not an easy task at all.

Based on my experience, I would suggest to either:

- stick to the simplest email validation regex, `^.+@.+$` and send a confirmation email with an activation link;

or

- avoid using regular expressions at all and use a library like my [EmailVerify for .NET](http://cobisi.com/email-validation/.net-component), which exposes a custom, fine tuned finite state machine for validating email addresses according to (*all* of) the related IETF standards plus disposable, DNS, SMTP, mailbox tests.

Obviously you can mix the two alternatives and perhaps avoid using regular expressions but send a confirmation link anyway.

Disclaimer: I am the tech lead of EmailVerify for .NET, a Microsoft .NET component for [validating email addresses](http://cobisi.com/email-validation/.net-component).

Answer (score 0):

The regex below forbids w.-a.wsdf.com

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(email, @"\A[a-z0-9]+([-._][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,4}\z")
        && Regex.IsMatch(email, @"^(?=.{1,64}@.{4,64}$)(?=.{6,100}$).*");
}
```

See [validate email address using regular expression in C#](http://seaf-email.blogspot.com/p/code.html#csharp).

Answer (score -1):

Take a text input in html and a button input like this 


Now when the button is clicked then the JavaScript function SubmitFunction() will be called. Now write the bellow code in this function.

```
function checkEmail() {

    var email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
    alert('Please provide a valid email address');
    email.focus;
    return false;
 }
}
```

**its works **